# Css hack for firefox, ie8, ie7, and ie6

Tags: css

For css like below could anyone tell me how I can apply css hacks for firefox, ie8, ie7, and ie6?

```
#category_area {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#categorytree ul {
  margin: 13px 10px 0px 5px;
}

#categorytree li {
  font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Note: Much of the CSS-Hack are NOT valid! The site postet by @mr.d shows you which hackes you shouldn't use when you want a valid CSS.

Comment: Thanks and I will work on it. Too many hacks to choose.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't make a **common** *hacked selector* for both `IE 8-` and `FF`.

You can get `IE` 8 and lower uniquely with the `\9` hack at the end of the settings.

A css hack for `FF` would be the `@-moz-document url-prefix()` wrapper.

Here's an example.

```
#category_area {
    margin-bottom: 10px\9;
}
#categorytree ul {
    margin: 13px 10px 0px 5px\9;
}

 @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    #category_area {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #categorytree ul {
        margin: 13px 10px 0px 5px;
    }
}
```

BTW - [5 Reasons to Avoid CSS Hacks and Conditional Stylesheets](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-reasons-to-avoid-css-hacks-and-conditional-stylesheets/)

Comment: Thanks, good information, and I really appreciated. I am trying to apply those hacks that you gave me every possible way, but seems not working yet. There could be some other problems for java script or templates. I will keep working on it.